# "E518: Unknown option: conf" when starting vim

Tags: vim

Something updated on my system recently and now, for certain file types, I'm getting this type of error on startup:

```
"/etc/pacman.conf" [readonly] 100L, 2910C
Error detected while processing FileType Auto commands for "*":
E518: Unknown option: conf
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I can make this go away if I comment out this line in my .vimrc:

```
syntax on
```

However, while editing /etc/pacman.conf, I can do a

```
set syntax conf
```

And everything looks great. So for some reason it's not understanding the .conf file type and erroring, but I'm not sure how to configure syntax to do the right thing automatically.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve?